# not able to consume thezipcodes.com search api data

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, geocoding, zipcode

I am new in nodejs and I want to use [www.thezipcodes.com](https://thezipcodes.com) `/api/v1/search` api to search the zip code to locatioin.

I am not able to use the location returned by the API.

```js
const request = require('request');
request('https://thezipcodes.com/api/v1/search?zipCode=13040&countryCode=US&apiKey=<apiKey>', (err, res, body) => {
    if (err) { return console.log(err); }    
    console.log(body.location);
});
```

Output is

```
undefined
```

In curl it is giving the output but in nodeapi I am not able to use the location array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should follow the example given in docs.
You are receiving JSON response in string from. Please parse the body object as JSON first and then use the result.